# Problem with abbreviations spacing in acronyms list

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, acronyms

I would like to have the acronyms at the same level, with the same separation. I'm using the next MDPI definition:

```
\begin{document}{article}

\newcommand{\abbreviations}[1]{%
\vspace{12pt}\noindent{\selectfont\textbf{Abbreviations \& Acronyms}\par\vspace{3pt}\noindent {\fontsize{9}{12.0}\selectfont #1}\par}}

\begin{abbreviations}{The following abbreviations and acronyms are used in this manuscript:\\}
\noindent
appm \makebox[2in]{\dotfill} Atomic Parts Per Million \\
Al \makebox[2in]{\dotfill} Aluminium\\
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: please give your question a meaningful title, and don't show only screenshots. Add a small but complete example that can be used for tests.

Comment: Hello and welcome René, you may like to read our [TeX.SX starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436), and know how to ask properly a question here, providing a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Oh I see, I'm sorry guys. I'll try to change it

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the abbreviations inside the `\makebox`. Then it aligns correctly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\makebox[2in]{appm \dotfill} Atomic Parts Per Million \\
\makebox[2in]{Al \dotfill} Aluminium \\

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\mindotfill}{%
  \nolinebreak
  {\def\hfill{\hskip 1cm plus 1fill\relax}%
   \dotfill
  }%
}

\begin{document}

test test test\mindotfill 123\\
test test test test test test \mindotfill 123\\
test test test test test test test test test test test\mindotfill 123\\
 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'll try it! Thank you

Comment: @RenéAlba did it help You?

Comment: Yeah kind of, thank you mate!